# Why is the GPU being underutilized during DQN training

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, gpu

I'm working on a DQN implementation in TensorFlow, but I'm facing performance issues with low GPU utilization. When the model is training, CPU rises to about 50%, GPU utilization stays <5%. Here is some information about the system

- WSL2 (version 2 - Ubuntu distribution)
- Python 3.10.12
- Tensorflow 2.15.0
- GPU: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1070

I do see a slight increase in GPU memory when the model trains.

These are the things I've tried to try and pinpoint the issue (unfortunately without success).

- Lowering the amount of features (20 -> 1);
- Lowering the amount of data (few thousand rows with 1 feature compared to the complete set;
- Different batch_sizes (8, 16, 32 .. 512);
- Less layers in the model, or less neurons;

None of the changes above had any impact on GPU utilization. Below you find some insights gathered during debugging which hopefully helps.

```
print(tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU'))
[PhysicalDevice(name='/physical_device:GPU:0', device_type='GPU')]
```

Below you find snakeviz profiling output:

- [snakeviz visual](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6xe6A.png)
- [snakeviz text output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8bT8N.png)

Output `nvidia-smi` during model training

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 551.61                 Driver Version: 551.61         CUDA Version: 12.4     |
|-----------------------------------------+------------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name                     TCC/WDDM  | Bus-Id          Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp   Perf          Pwr:Usage/Cap |           Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                                         |                        |               MIG M. |
|=========================================+========================+======================|
|   0  NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1070      WDDM  |   00000000:01:00.0  On |                  N/A |
|  0%   45C    P8             14W /  230W |     898MiB /   8192MiB |      6%      Default |
|                                         |                        |                  N/A |
+-----------------------------------------+------------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                              |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                              GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                               Usage      |
|=========================================================================================|
|    0   N/A  N/A      2924    C+G   C:\Windows\explorer.exe                     N/A      |
|    0   N/A  N/A      4188    C+G   ...05.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe\Cortana.exe      N/A      |
|    0   N/A  N/A      4544    C+G   ...2txyewy\StartMenuExperienceHost.exe      N/A      |
|    0   N/A  N/A      7680    C+G   ...siveControlPanel\SystemSettings.exe      N/A      |
|    0   N/A  N/A      7876    C+G   ....5336.0_x64__8j3eq9eme6ctt\IGCC.exe      N/A      |
|    0   N/A  N/A      8116    C+G   ...5n1h2txyewy\ShellExperienceHost.exe      N/A      |
|    0   N/A  N/A      9136    C+G   ...1.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe\Video.UI.exe      N/A      |
|    0   N/A  N/A      9468    C+G   ...crosoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe      N/A      |
|    0   N/A  N/A     10812    C+G   ...CBS_cw5n1h2txyewy\TextInputHost.exe      N/A      |
|    0   N/A  N/A     14420    C+G   ...Local\1Password\app\7\1Password.exe      N/A      |
|    0   N/A  N/A     14800    C+G   ....Search_cw5n1h2txyewy\SearchApp.exe      N/A      |
|    0   N/A  N/A     15064    C+G   ...ekyb3d8bbwe\PhoneExperienceHost.exe      N/A      |
|    0   N/A  N/A     15772    C+G   ...GeForce Experience\NVIDIA Share.exe      N/A      |
|    0   N/A  N/A     16712    C+G   ...21.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe\GameBar.exe      N/A      |
|    0   N/A  N/A     17300    C+G   ...oogle\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe      N/A      |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

This is the output in the console during training containing a few messages:

```
$ python3 train.py
2024-02-25 21:44:51.679317: E external/local_xla/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:9261] Unable to register cuDNN factory: Attempting to register factory for plugin cuDNN when one has already been registered
2024-02-25 21:44:51.679382: E external/local_xla/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_fft.cc:607] Unable to register cuFFT factory: Attempting to register factory for plugin cuFFT when one has already been registered
2024-02-25 21:44:51.680355: E external/local_xla/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_blas.cc:1515] Unable to register cuBLAS factory: Attempting to register factory for plugin cuBLAS when one has already been registered
2024-02-25 21:44:51.685519: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:182] This TensorFlow binary is optimized to use available CPU instructions in performance-critical operations.
To enable the following instructions: AVX2 FMA, in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
2024-02-25 21:44:52.341459: W tensorflow/compiler/tf2tensorrt/utils/py_utils.cc:38] TF-TRT Warning: Could not find TensorRT
2024-02-25 21:44:53.460875: I external/local_xla/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_executor.cc:887] could not open file to read NUMA node: /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:01:00.0/numa_node
Your kernel may have been built without NUMA support.
2024-02-25 21:44:53.486208: I external/local_xla/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_executor.cc:887] could not open file to read NUMA node: /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:01:00.0/numa_node
Your kernel may have been built without NUMA support.
2024-02-25 21:44:53.486310: I external/local_xla/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_executor.cc:887] could not open file to read NUMA node: /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:01:00.0/numa_node
Your kernel may have been built without NUMA support.
2024-02-25 21:44:54.083594: I external/local_xla/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_executor.cc:887] could not open file to read NUMA node: /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:01:00.0/numa_node
Your kernel may have been built without NUMA support.
2024-02-25 21:44:54.083741: I external/local_xla/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_executor.cc:887] could not open file to read NUMA node: /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:01:00.0/numa_node
Your kernel may have been built without NUMA support.
2024-02-25 21:44:54.083853: I external/local_xla/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_executor.cc:887] could not open file to read NUMA node: /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:01:00.0/numa_node
Your kernel may have been built without NUMA support.
2024-02-25 21:44:54.250900: I external/local_xla/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_executor.cc:887] could not open file to read NUMA node: /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:01:00.0/numa_node
Your kernel may have been built without NUMA support.
2024-02-25 21:44:54.251023: I external/local_xla/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_executor.cc:887] could not open file to read NUMA node: /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:01:00.0/numa_node
Your kernel may have been built without NUMA support.
2024-02-25 21:44:54.251055: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:2022] Could not identify NUMA node of platform GPU id 0, defaulting to 0.  Your kernel may not have been built with NUMA support.
2024-02-25 21:44:54.251145: I external/local_xla/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_executor.cc:887] could not open file to read NUMA node: /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:01:00.0/numa_node
Your kernel may have been built without NUMA support.
2024-02-25 21:44:54.251203: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1929] Created device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 6717 MB memory:  -> device: 0, name: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1070, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 6.1
2024-02-25 21:44:54.355782: I external/local_tsl/tsl/platform/default/subprocess.cc:304] Start cannot spawn child process: No such file or directory
2024-02-25 21:44:55.068152: I external/local_xla/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:454] Loaded cuDNN version 8904
2024-02-25 21:44:56.662109: I external/local_xla/xla/service/service.cc:168] XLA service 0x7f039c029f20 initialized for platform CUDA (this does not guarantee that XLA will be used). Devices:
2024-02-25 21:44:56.662152: I external/local_xla/xla/service/service.cc:176]   StreamExecutor device (0): NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1070, Compute Capability 6.1
2024-02-25 21:44:56.668128: I tensorflow/compiler/mlir/tensorflow/utils/dump_mlir_util.cc:269] disabling MLIR crash reproducer, set env var `MLIR_CRASH_REPRODUCER_DIRECTORY` to enable.
WARNING: All log messages before absl::InitializeLog() is called are written to STDERR
I0000 00:00:1708893896.734082  332735 device_compiler.h:186] Compiled cluster using XLA!  This line is logged at most once for the lifetime of the process.
```

Below you find the code that I'm using to train the model.

```
import os
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import random
import pdb
import tensorflow as tf
import datetime
import statsmodels.api as sm
import tensorflow as tf

from collections import deque
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import LSTM, Dense
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

gpus = tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')
if gpus:
   tf.config.set_visible_devices(gpus[0], 'GPU')  # Using only one GPU
   tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(gpus[0], True)

class DQNAgent:
    def __init__(self, state_size, action_size):
        self.state_size = state_size
        self.action_size = action_size
        self.memory = deque(maxlen=2000)
        self.gamma = 0.95  # Discount rate
        self.epsilon = 1.0  # Exploration rate
        self.epsilon_decay = 0.995
        self.epsilon_min = 0.05
        self.learning_rate = 0.00025
        self.model = self._build_model()
        self.checkpoint_callback = ModelCheckpoint(filepath='rl_model.keras',
                                                   save_best_only=True,
                                                   verbose=1)

    def _build_model(self):
        model = Sequential()
        model.add(LSTM(128, input_shape=(1, self.state_size)))
        model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
        model.add(Dense(self.action_size, activation='linear'))
        model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=self.learning_rate), metrics=['mean_absolute_error'])
        return model

    def remember(self, state, action, reward, next_state, done):
        self.memory.append((state, action, reward, next_state, done))

    def act(self, state):
        if np.random.rand() <= self.epsilon:
            return random.randrange(self.action_size)
        act_values = self.model.predict(state, verbose=0) # Returns Q-value of both actions
        return np.argmax(act_values[0])  # Returns action based on Q-value
    
    def replay(self, batch_size, val_data):
        def experience_generator():
            minibatch = random.sample(self.memory, batch_size)
            for state, action, reward, next_state, done in minibatch:
                target = reward
                if not done:
                    target = reward + self.gamma * np.amax(self.model.predict(next_state, verbose=0)[0])
                target_f = self.model.predict(state, verbose=0)
                target_f[0][action] = target
                
                yield state, target_f

        steps_per_epoch = len(self.memory) // batch_size
        self.model.fit(
            experience_generator(), 
            epochs=8, 
            steps_per_epoch=steps_per_epoch, 
            verbose=0
        )

        if self.epsilon > self.epsilon_min:
            self.epsilon *= self.epsilon_decay

def preprocess_data(df):
    df = df['number']

    return df

def main():
    # Load Bitcoin data
    df = pd.read_csv('data_sets/train.csv')
    train_data, val_data = train_test_split(df, test_size=0.2, random_state=42, shuffle=False)

    # Preprocess data
    train_data = preprocess_data(train_data)
    val_data = preprocess_data(val_data)
    train_data.dropna(inplace=True)
    val_data.dropna(inplace=True)
    state_size = len(train_data.columns)
    action_size = 2  # 0: buy, 1: sell

    # Initialize DQN agent
    agent = DQNAgent(state_size, action_size)
    # Training parameters
    batch_size = 512
    episodes = 1
    episode_steps = 750

    for episode in range(episodes):
        start_time = datetime.datetime.now()
        state = train_data.iloc[0]  # Initial state
        state = np.reshape(state, [1, 1, state_size])
        total_reward = 0
        correct_actions = 0
        total_actions = 0

        for time_step in range(episode_steps):
            total_steps = len(train_data) * episodes
            current_step = time_step + episode_steps * episode
            action = agent.act(state)
            next_state = train_data.iloc[current_step + 1].values  # Add .values
            next_state = np.reshape(next_state, [1, 1, state_size])
            reward = calculate_reward(train_data.iloc[current_step], train_data.iloc[current_step + 1], action)
            total_reward += reward
            if reward > 0:
              correct_actions += 1
              total_actions += 1
            else:
              total_actions += 1
            done = time_step == episode_steps - 2
            agent.remember(state, action, reward, next_state, done)
            state = next_state
            if current_step % 25 == 0:
                print(f"{current_step} - {round(total_reward, 2)} - Epsilon: {round(agent.epsilon, 2)}, Accuracy: {round((correct_actions / total_actions * 100), 2)}%")

            if done:
                break

            if len(agent.memory) > batch_size:
                agent.replay(batch_size, val_data)

def calculate_reward(current_state, next_state, action):
    return 1 # Test to see utilization change GPU/CPU

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: The model is very simple, so it needs little computation.